¿Cómo filtrar por oficinas mediante sentencia sql en sql server?
tengo 3 tablas en una BD de sql server. Son: oficinas, noticias y noticias_oficinas. En noticias_oficinas y dado que una noticia puede pertenecer a más de una oficina, es donde guardo id_oficina e id_noticia.
Hasta quí bien, el tema es que tengo otra tabla llamada control_registros donde guardo cuando los usuarios han leído/modificado/eliminado las noticias pero como también la utilizo para otras tablas, hice que en un campo llamado tabla_nombre se guardase el nombre de la tabla y en otro campo llamado tabla_id el valor de la id.
En la pantalla principal muestro las últimas modificaciones realizadas siempre y cuando no se hayan eliminado las noticias y me funciona correctamente pero ahora quiero filtrar por oficina y no veo cómo hacer el join entre tabla_id de control_registros y id_noticia en tabla noticias_oficinas. Os adjunto como tengo la consulta sql:
SELECT distinct [L1].*, CONVERT(DATETIME2(0), [L1].[Fecha_alta]) as da from [Control_Registros] L1 LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Usuarios ON [L1].[Id_usuario] = dbo.Usuarios.Id_usuario  where (Tabla_nombre='Noticias' and (Tipo_accion='Alta' or Tipo_accion='Modificación') and not exists (select [L2].[Tabla_Id] from [Control_Registros] L2 where [L1].[Tabla_Id] = [L2].[Tabla_Id] and [L2].[Tipo_accion] = 'Eliminación' and [L2].[Tabla_nombre] = 'Noticias')) ORDER BY Fecha_alta desc OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 10 ROWS ONLY

Gracias de antemano, saludos.

Tendrás que poner la estructura de las tablas (genera un script por ejemplo, mejor incluso si añades en el script los datos de ejemplo) para poder entender el problema y darte una solución concreta.

Si no pones las  tablas, las respuestas van a ser teóricas o inexactas. Lo que se me o curre es que deberías hacer un select de registros con un join de noticias_oficinas y este a su vez con noticias y con oficinas.
Select * from control_registros CR
inner join noticias N on N.Id = CR.tabla_id AND CR.TablanNombre = 'Noticias'
inner join noticias_oficinas NO on NO.id_noticia = N.id
inner join oficinas O on O.id = NO.id_oficina
where (CR.Tipo_accion = 'Alta' or CR.Tipo_accion = 'Modificacion') and O.nombre == 'Nombre oficina'  -- aquí se añade el filtro según oficina que como no se las columnas de la tabla son teóricas


Gracias Suso, lo he solventado de ésta manera !
